# Is it possible to run a command on closing on Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that has :start in the beginning, and goto start at the end (with a  3 minute delay between them). I have it log everything, but I want it to log to a text file on closing. I know how to log (echo (%time%) [command] >> log.txt), but can it log "(%time%) Program Closed" when it's closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>log.txt echo (%time%) [start myProgram]
myProgram.exe
>>log.txt echo (%time%) [myProgram closed]
```